# Android: start a worker thread from UI thread hang the application

Tags: android, multithreading, freeze

I have written below codes. Every time I run it, Application stops. 
Could you help me with any any idea?

If I don't start the worker thread, the code was okay. 
My question is:

Can I start a worker thread from `onCreate` function on the UI thread?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private Bluetooth mBluetooth = null;
    private Gauge mGauge;
    private Obd2 mObd2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        mGauge = findViewById(R.id.gauge1);
        mGauge.setValue(120);
        mBluetooth = new Bluetooth();
        try {
            mBluetooth.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mObd2 = new Obd2(mBluetooth);
        mObd2.command(obd2CommandEnum.RESET);

        runRPMThread();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void runRPMThread() {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mGauge.setValue(mObd2.rpm());
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(300);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: show log,please?

Comment: Yes, but be aware that the thread will execute beyond the Activity lifecycle which can result in various issues such as crashes and memory leaks. You either want to ensure the process is cancelled or executed in a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just debugged into the issue...there was a null pointer in mObd2.rpm() function. I need to run the application with a connection to my car with bluetooth. without that, I have a null pointer...